# Swift Firebase - Return results for all users events in a feed

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to display all of the events by all of the users, but so far I'm stuck with only displaying the events from the current.

Here's my code:

```
self.dbRef.child("user_profiles").child(self.activeUser!.uid).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) in
            self.activeUserData = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary

            //Get Events
            self.dbRef.child("events/\(self.activeUser!.uid)").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) in

                    self.events.append(snapshot.value as! NSDictionary)




                    self.homeTableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row:0, section:0)], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.automatic)

                    self.aivLoading.stopAnimating()
                }

            ){(error) in
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }

        }
```

My Firebase tree looks like this:

```
events
   - UserID (user who posted the event)
      - eventID
         - eventDetails
```

Is there a way to display all of the events from all of the users? Or does my database need to be restructured? And, if so, how?

Answer (score 0):

Since your Firebase tree looks like:

```
events
   - UserID (user who posted the event)
      - eventID
         - eventDetails
```

To get all the events from all the users you need to get all the userIDs, then you can simply loop through userIDs and get all the events.

Or you can restructure your Firebase like:

```
events
   - eventID
      - eventDetails
      - userID (user who posted the event)
```

And in user child:

```
user
   - userID
      - events
         - eventID
```